# how to extend child template to parent in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails. I am having difficulty in understanding template inheritance. Earlier I have worked in django and seen template inheritence there. There I saw child is told about parent using "extends" command. Can anyone explain how it works here. I have gone through guidelines of ruby but it was not clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple to do in Rails.

You simply tell the template you are currently rendering to render another template.

For example `layouts/application.html.erb` contains something like this:

```
<% content_for :navigation do %>
<nav>...</nav>
<% end %>     

<% content_for :content do %>                                                                                                                                                                       
<%= yield %>                                                                                                                                                                                        
<% end %>                                                                                                                                                                                           

<%= render :template => 'layouts/main_application' %>
```

The important part is the `render :template` part that then delegates this template to also render the `layouts/main_application.html.erb` that in my case looks something like this:

```
<header>
...
</header>
<body>
<%= yield :nav %>
<%= content_for?(:content) ? yield(:content) : yield %> 
</body>
```

What I am doing here is having a main template that does not contain the navigation (for things like login etc) and the application.html.erb adds that navigation to the `:nav` content placeholder.

Comment: can you also tell me how to extend engine application.html.erb template to application's application.html.erb template.

Comment: Sorry I have not tried writing my own rails engines yet so I can't help you there.. But look at the Rails code... It's surprisingly readable and logical :)